# How to create .mbtiles file?

Tags: ios, iphone, tilemill, mbtiles

I have tiles (png images) for an offline map and I want to create a .mbtiles-file using these tiles. Please help me how to create a .mbtiles-file using my own images not using Tilemill software?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use globalmapper to export *.mbtiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .mbtiles file is a sqlite3 database following the mbtiles specification: https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.2/spec.md

Answer (score 5):

Have you had a look at Tilemill?

http://mapbox.com/blog/create-a-custom-map-of-your-city-in-30-minutes-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap/

Comment: What do you mean by 'now it's not require'?

Comment: means I was asking this question at 19th march '12 and your answer date is May 16 '12 so in between had got solution my self. that's why i was comment that "now it's not require.:)